Plotting Error using vectorBT - Lack of column or index argument
When I run the following code below, I get an error regarding a lack of an index or column= argument. But I don't know how to do this. I have tried common ones like [0] or [returns] but just get the following error about not specifying it correctly.
import vectorbt as vbt
import datetime

end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=3)

btc_price = vbt.YFData.download(
['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', 'XMR-USD', 'ADA-USD'], 
    interval='1m', 
    start = start_date,
    end = end_date, 
    missing_index='drop'
).get('Close')

print(btc_price)

fast_ma = vbt.MA.run(btc_price, window=59)
slow_ma = vbt.MA.run(btc_price, window=200)

entries = fast_ma.ma_crossed_above(slow_ma)
exits = fast_ma.ma_crossed_below(slow_ma)

pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(btc_price, entries, exits)

print(pf.total_return())

pf.plot().show()

Here is the output
c:\Users\Kishan\anaconda3\envs\vectorbt\Lib\site-    packages\vectorbt\data\base.py:527: UserWarning:

 Symbols have mismatching index. Dropping missing data points.

 C:\Users\Kishan\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26556\3025894811.py:27:                UserWarning:


 Subplot 'orders' raised an exception

symbol                          BTC-USD      ETH-USD     XMR-USD   ADA-USD
Datetime                                                                  
2024-07-24 10:36:00+00:00  66422.640625  3464.827881  161.282486  0.416950
2024-07-24 10:37:00+00:00  66423.968750  3465.011719  161.294678  0.417531
2024-07-24 10:38:00+00:00  66427.703125  3465.592285  161.296356  0.417586
2024-07-24 10:39:00+00:00  66440.929688  3466.455322  161.312042  0.417648
2024-07-24 10:40:00+00:00  66435.421875  3466.446289  161.288239  0.418152
...                                 ...          ...         ...       ...
2024-07-27 10:28:00+00:00  68181.031250  3274.723389  163.000778  0.417045
2024-07-27 10:29:00+00:00  68183.343750  3275.549316  163.029144  0.417034
2024-07-27 10:30:00+00:00  68179.210938  3276.020508  163.007492  0.417039
2024-07-27 10:31:00+00:00  68176.718750  3276.399170  163.057693  0.416996
2024-07-27 10:32:00+00:00  68181.343750  3275.568115  163.113449  0.416996

[4078 rows x 4 columns]
    ma_window  ma_window  symbol 
    59         200        BTC-USD   -0.014620
                      ETH-USD   -0.030326
                      XMR-USD    0.053941
                      ADA-USD    0.031189
   Name: total_return, dtype: float64

